# Converting base-64 string to image in pure java

Tags: java, image, base64

I need to send pictures from raspberry pi (written in python) to server (in java). I have read that the easiest way is to encode image to base64 send it and decode on the server side.
Now I have a generated base64 txt file from png. 
I need a program to decode it.

I have folder in which I have my base64 code(64kb in one line of txt file)

encoding program that looks like

```
import urllib
encoded = urllib.quote(open("/home/wojtek/Desktop/wideo/nazdjecia/test_image1.png", "rb").read().encode("base64"))
print encoded
f = open("path/obr.txt",'w')
f.write(encoded)
f.close()
print "done"
```

and program that looks like this

```
public class JavaApplication2 {

    public static BufferedImage decodeToImage(String imageString)
    {
    BufferedImage image = null;
    byte[] imageByte;
    try
    {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        imageByte = decoder.decodeBuffer(imageString);
        ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageByte);
        image = ImageIO.read(bis);
        bis.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/filepath/obr.txt"));
            String str;
            str = in.readLine();

        NewJFrame gui = new NewJFrame();
        gui.setVisible(true);
        BufferedImage im = decodeToImage(str);
        ImageIcon ico = new ImageIcon(im);
        gui.imgset(ico );
            // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }

}
```

when I try to decode it with java it crashes

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -javaagent:/usr/share/java/jayatanaag.jar
>   javax.imageio.IIOException: Error skipping PNG metadata   at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:680)
>     at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(PNGImageReader.java:1229)
>     at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(PNGImageReader.java:1577)
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1448)    at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1352)     at
>   javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.decodeToImage(JavaApplication2.java:33)
>     at javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:55)
>   Caused by: java.io.EOFException   at
>   javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStreamImpl.readInt(ImageInputStreamImpl.java:251)
>     at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readMetadata(PNGImageReader.java:666)
>     ... 6 more java.lang.NullPointerException   at
>   javax.swing.ImageIcon.(ImageIcon.java:228)  at
>   javaapplication2.JavaApplication2.main(JavaApplication2.java:56)

what am I doing wrong... :(

Comment: What are you using to write the PNG to Base64? It looks like your Base64 is missing some important information, considering that it got to EOF and was expecting to read an int.

Comment: Do you need to specify that you're writing binary in your python script, i.e. f = open("path/obr.txt", "wb") ?

Comment: What is `BASE64Decoder`? Why aren't you using [`Base64.Decoder`?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getDecoder--) Can you verify that the decoded data are intact? For example, compare the hash of decoded data with the hash of the original file.

Comment: @TrentSmall He's writing text. Base-64 encoding is all US-ASCII text.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is, why the heck are you using Base64? If you have control over both programs, send and receive binary. Second, be sure the Base64 variants you are using are *compatible*. Unlike the name suggest there are *many* variants: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64